# How can i create a file name that will include also the date and time of the first day and the last day?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm not sure yet how the format of the file name should be the idea is to make somehow the file name to be built from the first date and time of when the first file added to the List and the date time when it's creating the animated gif file:

```
private void CreateAnimatedGif(bool ToCreate)
{
    if (ToCreate == false)
    {
        AnimatedGifFiles.Add(last_file);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AnimatedGifFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!AnimatedGifFiles[i].Contains(last_file))
                AnimatedGifFiles.Add(last_file);
        }
        if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count > 1)
        {
            unfreezWrapper1.MakeGIF(AnimatedGifFiles, AnimatedGifDirectory, 80, true);
        }
        AnimatedGifFiles = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

This method is being called each X seconds only when a website provide new image each time and the image was download to my hard disk.

Then the method can be called for hours sometimes even days 3-4 days.

As long as the variable ToCreate is false it will keep adding files to the List AnimatedGifFiles.
Then after some hours or it can be even some days the variable ToCreate is true and then it will create the Animated gif file.

For now in this line i gave it only a directory:

```
unfreezWrapper1.MakeGIF(AnimatedGifFiles, AnimatedGifDirectory, 80, true);
```

AnimatedGifDirectory is a path with a directory. But it should be with a file name in the end for exmaple: c:\test\AnimatedGifFile\Animated.gif

But now it's only c:\test\AnimatedGifFile\

I'm not sure how to create the file name using the first added file to the List date and time and the date and time when the Animated gif file was created.

Something like: 12/12/04_12/22/04.gif
I want that the user will know according to the file name the dates of the event when the event started 12/12/04 and when it was ended 12/22/04

And then after some hours or days again the method will be called so the next file name will be for example: 01/10/05_01/13/05.gif

And so on but i'm not sure how to create a file name with the first added file date time and in the end the date time and what kind of format of the file to make ?

Maybe something like: First-12/12/04_Last-12/22/04.gif
Or maybe : Event-12/12/04-12/22/04.gif

I wanted to add also the time in each side when started and ended but that might make the file too long.

Or

Maybe the easiest way will be to create for each event a directory for example:

Event-12/12/04-12/22/04

And inside to create a shorter gif file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function this way. You can adjust the way the dates are formatted. Note the `dateTime` member variable.

```
private List<string> AnimatedGifFiles;
private  DateTime startTime;  // new!!

private void CreateAnimatedGif(bool ToCreate)
{
    if(AnimatedGifFiles.Count == 0)   // new!!
      startTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (ToCreate == false)
    {
        AnimatedGifFiles.Add(last_file);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AnimatedGifFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!AnimatedGifFiles[i].Contains(last_file))
                AnimatedGifFiles.Add(last_file);
        }
        if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count > 1)
        {
            string outputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(   // new!!
                AnimatedGifDirectory, 
                string.Format(
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                    "Event-{0:yyyy-MM-dd}-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}.gif", startTime, DateTime.Now)); 

            unfreezWrapper1.MakeGIF(AnimatedGifFiles, outputFile, 80, true); //new!!
        }
        AnimatedGifFiles = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried you solution and i have a problem C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\AnimatedGifDirectory\Event-10/23/2014-10/23/2014 this is the directory in the outputFile variable. But MakeGIF should get a file name for example C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\AnimatedGifDirectory\Event-10/23/2014-10/23/2014.Gif so i tried in this line to do: unfreezWrapper1.MakeGIF(AnimatedGifFiles, outputFile + ".Gif", 80, true); i added + ".Gif" but it didn't help. I'm not getting any errors or exceptions it's just not creating the animated gif file in the directory.

Comment: Yes I didn't notice that a dash (`/`) shouldn't exist in file pathes. I edited in my post to the usual format (see other posts) and added the `.gif` extension. Just replace the format string in for the outputFile variable an try it again.

Comment: Fratyx working good. Uf i want to add also time to the file ? I tried to change this part of the outputFile variable: "Event-{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}_{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}.gif" so it's adding the time but the time is the same in both sides start and end. How can i make that the time on the right will be of the start and the date on the right of the end ? What i got for example now is: C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\mws\My Weather Station\AnimatedGifDirectory\Event-2014-10-23 12:14:42_2014-10-23 12:14:42.gif and the line MakeGIF even not saving this file to the hard disk. How can i add time?

Comment: What i mean is that the outputFile variable the time is the same exactly same time on the left and right sides. The time should be different. Also it didn't create this file at all.

Comment: There is the next problem that also `:` is not allowed in file names. And better dont use spaces. And it was my fault that both dates are equal as both I put the `0` twice in the format string. (I fixed it in the post.) I would suggest something like that to fix these problems `"Event_{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss}.gif"`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I changed the format to match [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

First, I would reommend that you use a date format that is easy to sort by: 2014_10_22, for example.
File name format can then be :
<strike>2014_10_22__2014_10_23_1900.gif</strike> **2014-10-22__2014-10-23T1900.gif**

or better for sorting (if it is possible that several files wikll be created in the same date):
<strike>2014_10_22__1600__56h.gif</strike> **2014-10-22T1600__56h.gif** 
(where1600 is 4pm - start time of the file, and 56 is the length of time in hours)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend 2014-10-22 over 2014_10_22, as that's an ISO-8601 compliant format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private string startDateTime = "";

private void CreateAnimatedGif(bool ToCreate)
{
    string endDateTime; 

    if (ToCreate == false)
    {
        if(startDateTime == ""){startDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH'h'mm'm'ss's'_");}
        AnimatedGifFiles.Add(last_file);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!AnimatedGifFiles.Contains(last_file))
        {
            AnimatedGifFiles.Add(last_file);
        }
        if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count > 1)
        {
            endDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH'h'mm'm'ss's.gif'");
            unfreezWrapper1.MakeGIF(AnimatedGifFiles,  AnimatedGifDirectory+ startDateTime + endDateTime, 80, true);
        }
        startDateTime = "";
        //You don't create a new list. Clear the existing one
        if(AnimatedGifFiles.Count != 0){AnimatedGifFiles.Clear();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not clearly understand your code, but i think you trying to do something like that:

```
    private void CreateAnimatedGif(bool ToCreate) {
        string dateOfCreate;

        if (ToCreate == false)
        {
            if(AnimatedGifFiles.Count == 0) // that means it's the first element in the list
            {
                dateOfCreate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
            AnimatedGifFiles.Add(last_file);
        }
        else
        {
            if(AnimatedGifFiles.Count == 0) // that means it's the first element in the list
            {
                dateOfCreate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
            if (!AnimatedGifFiles.Contains(last_file))
            {
                AnimatedGifFiles.Add(last_file);
            }
            if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count > 1)
            {
                unfreezWrapper1.MakeGIF(AnimatedGifFiles, AnimatedGifDirectory + dateOfCreate + DateTime.Now.ToString(), 80, true);
            }
            AnimatedGifFiles = new List<string>();
        }
}
```